# validate sessions using operators in php

Tags: php, validation, session

I want to validate whether a user is logged in and if the user is authorized to view content using php.

```
if($_SESSION['log'] != "1"){
if($_SESSION['type'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "2" || $_SESSION['type'] != "3"){
    header("Location: redirect.php");
}}
```

This works perfectly.

But I want to check all in the same statement as below. But it is not working even for a correct login.

```
if($_SESSION['log'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "2" || $_SESSION['type'] != "3"){
    header("Location: redirect.php");
}
```

Comment: replace first || (or) with && (and) in second example and put everthing after && in brackets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic from your first set of code would indicate a slightly different if statement:

```
if($_SESSION['log'] != "1" && ($_SESSION['type'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "2" || $_SESSION['type'] != "3")){
    header("Location: redirect.php");
}
```

In your original working code, you only test the `type` session info if `log != 1` which means your second code may well be executing on ANY of the other clauses that would not be checked at all in the original.

Edit Your original code:

```
if($_SESSION['log'] != "1")
{
// This condition is ALWAYS checked.
    if($_SESSION['type'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "2" || $_SESSION['type'] != "3")
    {
    // These conditions are ONLY checked if the first check passes.
        header("Location: redirect.php");
    }
}
```

In your second example, all the conditions were being checked at the same time, and as you used an `OR` operator, if ANY of them passed, ir would evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fluffeh. It works. I think I have used wrong logic.

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka You do understand the difference in the code though yes? I added an edit to explain it more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way what is the difference between "||" and "|"?

Comment: @nirosharathnayaka A single `|` is a [bitwise operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). While the double pipe `||` is a [logical operator](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `&&` not `||`.

```
if($_SESSION['log'] != "1" && ($_SESSION['type'] != "1" || $_SESSION['type'] != "2" || $_SESSION['type'] != "3")){
    header("Location: redirect.php");
}
```

Or you could use `in_array`.

```
if ($_SESSION['log'] != "1" && !in_array($_SESSION['type'], array('1','2','3'))) {
  header("Location: redirect.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the presence of any non-zero value in `$_SESSION['type']` indicate a valid session?  If so, you could just do this:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['type'])) {
    header("Location: redirect.php");
}
```

Comment: No. It used to indicate specific authority level. 1 for admin, 2 for director etc.

Answer (score 0):

..Or use `in_array` for more readability

```
if ($_SESSION['log'] != "1" && !in_array($_SESSION['type'], array("1","2","3"))
```